# conversion of NSString to NSDecimal

Tags: objective-c

I need to convert NSString to NSDecimalNumber .
I tried this code

```
 payment.subTotal =[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:str1];
```

where str1 is my NSString from some other class which carries number from textfield.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith str1 is NSString globally declared in other class which containt textfield entered number

Comment: yes it is showing in NSLog properly but not accepting actuallly

Comment: what is its value? we need to know so we could reproduce it

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith subtotal is NSDecimalNumber

Comment: Write this in your code NSLog(str1); and give me the value of the result

Comment: str1 is always number entered through textfield

Comment: 2012-06-11 09:59:53.977 MobileEcommerce[1353:207] total amount 58259.000000

Comment: NSLog(@"total amount %@",str1)..

Comment: actually its not accepting . should i convert that str1 into nsdecimal number by some other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDecimalNumber* dec = (NSDecimalNumber *)str1;
```